# How much can i or should i migrate at once

Tags: database, migration

I am a student aspiring to become a backend developer.
Currently, I am developing a web application that uses mysql database that requires migrations.
Before this project, I have been doing migrations in one big chunk

for example

```
CREATE TABLE user;
CREATE TABLE account;
```

My question is, is it better to have one migration operation in one file or is it better space it out like

```
file 1

CREATE TABLE user;
```

```
file 2

CREATE TABLE account;
```

What are some good practices. Any advice or directions/references I should read.

Thank you for your time.